# How to use the "Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy"?

Tags: audio, actionscript, mp3, wav, encoder

I was trying to convert wav to mp3 in my actionscript project, and I was glad to find the https://github.com/phillockwood/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy
but my actionscript knowledge is so limited that I don't know how to use it in my project.

In my project, the function as follow, convert byteArray data into wav format, and I need to convert the wav into mp3. I know use th Shine-MP3-Encoder can do this job, but I just don't know where to place it in my project, and how to its function ...who can help me out ? I do do appreciate it~~

```
    public static function convertToWav(soundBytes:ByteArray, sampleRate:int):ByteArray   {
        var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        data.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;

        var numBytes:uint = soundBytes.length / 2; // soundBytes are 32bit floats, we are storing 16bit integers
        var numChannels:int = 1;
        var bitsPerSample:int = 16;

        // The following is from https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

        data.writeUTFBytes("RIFF"); // ChunkID
        data.writeUnsignedInt(36 + numBytes); // ChunkSize
        data.writeUTFBytes("WAVE"); // Format
        data.writeUTFBytes("fmt "); // Subchunk1ID
        data.writeUnsignedInt(16); // Subchunk1Size // 16 for PCM
        data.writeShort(1); // AudioFormat 1 Mono, 2 Stereo (Microphone is mono)
        data.writeShort(numChannels); // NumChannels
        data.writeUnsignedInt(sampleRate); // SampleRate
        data.writeUnsignedInt(sampleRate * numChannels * bitsPerSample/8); // ByteRate
        data.writeShort(numChannels * bitsPerSample/8); // BlockAlign
        data.writeShort(bitsPerSample); // BitsPerSample
        data.writeUTFBytes("data"); // Subchunk2ID
        data.writeUnsignedInt(numBytes); // Subchunk2Size

        soundBytes.position = 0;
        while(soundBytes.bytesAvailable > 0) {
            var sample:Number = soundBytes.readFloat(); // The sample is stored as a sine wave, -1 to 1
            var val:int = sample * 32768; // Convert to a 16bit integer
            data.writeShort(val);
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

- Use (ghostcat.media.WAVWriter) to convert a sound bytearray to a wav
- Use shine to conver this wav bytearray to an mp3 file

Look up that WAVWriter plugin, that made things really easy for me

Answer (score -1):

you can use this example with the "encodeClicked ()" function

https://github.com/cyrildiagne/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy/blob/master/src/fr/kikko/test/ShineMP3EncoderTest.as